# Unable to ssh into a machine over LAN

Tags: ssh

I am unable to ssh into a computer over the LAN.

```
t326@t326:~$ ssh  root@192.100.30.77
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
e8:ac:79:c0:ac:23:df:a1:77:11:b5:ea:f1:4f:2c:e1.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts:33
remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.100.30.77
ECDSA host key for 192.100.30.77 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I try to use the verbose mode of ssh to diagnose why I am getting this message.

```
t326@t326:~$ ssh -v  root@192.100.30.77
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.100.30.77 [192.100.30.77] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA e8:ac:79:c0:ac:23:df:a1:77:11:b5:ea:f1:4f:2c:e1
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
e8:ac:79:c0:ac:23:df:a1:77:11:b5:ea:f1:4f:2c:e1.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts:33
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.100.30.77
ECDSA host key for 192.100.30.77 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I do as suggested by the message above.

```
t326@t326:~$  ssh-keygen -f "/home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.100.30.77
# Host 192.100.30.77 found: line 33 type ECDSA
/home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts.old
```

Then I try to login once again :-

```
t326@t326:~$ ssh  root@192.100.30.77
The authenticity of host '192.100.30.77 (192.100.30.77)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is e8:ac:79:c0:ac:23:df:a1:77:11:b5:ea:f1:4f:2c:e1.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.100.30.77' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@192.100.30.77's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.100.30.77's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.100.30.77's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I try to debug it by being verbose : -

```
t326@t326:~$ ssh -vvv root@192.100.30.77
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.100.30.77 [192.100.30.77] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/t326/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.100.30.77" from file "/home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert- v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-   hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2- nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA e8:ac:79:c0:ac:23:df:a1:77:11:b5:ea:f1:4f:2c:e1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.100.30.77" from file "/home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.100.30.77' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/t326/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/t326/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/t326/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/t326/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/t326/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/t326/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/t326/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/t326/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/t326/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/t326/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/t326/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/t326/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.100.30.77's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 48 padlen 16 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.100.30.77's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 48 padlen 16 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.100.30.77's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 48 padlen 16 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
t326@t326:~$
```

Can someone please help me ? What am I doing wrong? Note : My client computer is on DHCP. So it probably gets a new ip everyday.For the last 1 week, I have been able to access this server sometimes and sometimes I am locked out as shown above.

Comment: looks like: 1. you don't have a key pair in your ~/.ssh/ and 2. the host you're trying to ssh into is configured to refuse password authentication and require public key for root (and possibly for anyh users too).  Can you login as a non-root user and then su to root?   if so, then you can generate a key pair on your local machine, ssh into the remote, su to root, and add your **PUBLIC** key to root's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Comment: btw, you can tell ssh to not check the remote host's key with `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ...`.   Use this **ONLY** when you know the status of the remote machine, and it would be unwise to do this at all without reading up on ssh and host keys and why the matter.

Comment: It's possible that some other system that is not your server is using your server's IP address.

Comment: @cas, Query 1 : the initial message says "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!", does that mean that the private and public key pair of the server have changed?  What could have changed the key pair on the server ?  Query 2: You are correct, there is no id_rsa / id_rsa.pub in the .ssh directory. May I ask where is this mentioned in the debugging information above ? Query 3 : I have intermittent access to the server. What could explain that sometimes I am able to access ( after repeating the  ssh-keygen -f "/home/t326/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.100.30.77 procedure ) and sometimes not.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick My server has a static IP while my client is on DHCP. My apologies, as this was not clear from my initial query.

Comment: 2. the `ssh -vvv` output shows it (e.g. `debug3: no such identity: /home/t326/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory`).   3. have you copied your ssh **PUBLIC** key into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host? e.g. via `ssh-copy-id` or by editing it manually.

Comment: 1. if you're getting "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" when ssh-ing into a server with a static IP, that generally means one of two things:  a) the host's public key has changed for some reason.  or b) there's another machine on your network claiming that IP (this could also explain why you can sometimes authenticate, but sometimes not) - is your client machine on the same subnet as the server?   If so, you could run `arpwatch` or similar on your client machine and get a warning when the MAC address associated with an IP address changes.

Comment: BTW, don't assume that just because you've claimed (or been assigned) an IP address on the network that some knucklehead won't come along and just use it because they can.  also , sorry to say this, but don't assume that it's not you being the knucklehead - has this IP address been assigned to you? do you have permission to use it? or have you just arbitrarily claimed the address?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I should assign static IP addresses to the servers. Then I should tell DHCP router that these addresses are taken. That should fix my problem?

Comment: yep, that should fix it.   it's a good idea to reserve part of the IP address range for static allocations, and another part (or the remainder) for dynamic.   You can even do static allocations with dhcpd (e.g. with rules like `host myserver { hardware ethernet xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx; fixed-address 192.100.30.77; }`, where xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is the server's MAC address)